# Using Tabs in a ContentPage Xamarin cross platform app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I have a xamarin cross platform application and my views are in the PCL project and from home page of my application i am using this code to navigate to a new page

```
        var target = new SelectPage();
        Navigation.PushAsync(target);
```

And the xaml of the  navigated page is like this

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SelectPage"           
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">  
      <Grid>
          want to show 3 tabs here
      </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
```

Whats the possibility of showing three listbox items in this page as tabs

Comment: what type of tab? Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi LIke a normal Tab control in WPF or http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp  .But in xamarin crossplatform  xaml

Comment: Use segmented button tabs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077382/xamarin-segmented-control-for-windows-uwp/39103153#39103153

Comment: Alternately could just navigate to a new Forms TabbedPage and create three pages to populate the TabbedPage with.